# Comparing two participant groups on multiple likert scale response options in exploratory study

Tags: t-test, factor-analysis, likert, manova, exploratory-data-analysis

Hi I am new to CrossValidate so wanted to thank anyone in advance for contributing and looking at my questions.

I am presently reviewing data from an exploratory study where two groups of participants were asked to indicate on a 7 point likert scale the extent to which each of the 20 items presented to them "influenced their decision-making". Although there is some distinction in the size of participant groups (60% to 40%) the data contains approximately 12000 participant so I should have reasonable power.

There are two analysis questions I would be greatful for any assistance with.

Question 1:
I want to be able to see if there's a difference between the two participant groups in the mean scores for each of these items.
So effectively I am looking at an IV of a dichotomous categorical variable and continuous/scale data DV.
Currently I'm a little bit indecisive as to whether I should run a MANOVA,or individual t-tests, or individual t-tests with a bonferroni correction. Or should I be maybe even looking at running an EFA to see if there are any items that hang nicely together and compare groups across these categories?

Question 2:
The analysis of question 2 is I guess an extension/alteration of question 1.
For this question I would like to compare the same participants groups across the same likert scale response options, across two different conditions.
This would be to assess if the different conditions affected the response options.

Participants were presented with the 20 response options in the first condition. And additionally presented the 20 items in the second condition. The part where it becomes really tricky here for me is that some participants exclusively responded in the first condition, some participants exclusively responded in the second condition, and some participants responded in both conditions. I believe this may result in assumptions of normality being violated so I may need to use nonparametric equivalents.

Overall I may be getting a little confused by the exploratory nature of this study in comparison to the experimental studies I am used to undertaking. As this area of research has such limited information available I am hoping to be able to provide researchers and practitioners in this field with some useful and practical information